# How to call input variable in IDLE without using f5 everytime

Tags: python, shell, python-idle

This is just some code, and I want to find a way to run the code without having to press f5 everytime. I'm looking for a command or way to call the input variable. Since when I put print (x) in the IDLE shell it gives me the input value. I could use an infinite loop but I'm wondering if it's possible?

```
x = int(input("Please enter an integer: "))

if x < 0:
    x = 0
    print('Negative changed to zero')
elif x == 0:
        print('Zero')
elif x == 1:
        print('Single')
else:
        print('More')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use an infinite loop:

```
while (True):
    x = int(input("Please enter an integer: "))

    if x < 0:
        x = 0
        print('Negative changed to zero')
    elif x == 0:
        print('Zero')
    elif x == 1:
        print('Single')
    else:
        print('More')
```